# Changing an Entry in the Pretty Print Dispatch Table (Common Lisp)

Tags: common-lisp, pretty-print

My lisp editor currently pprint indents `if` statements like so:

```
(if (test)
    'yes
  'no)
```

How to set the `*print-pprint-dispatch*` table to pprint instead:

```
(if (test)
  'yes
  'no)
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"My lisp editor"* If the editor is doing the pretty-printing, it can do so without necessarily calling a Common Lisp program that uses the dispatch table. If the editor is Emacs, maybe this question can help you: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10230/2583

Comment: unclear which 'lisp editor' you are using and how

Comment: Yes, you're right that it's the editor and not the lisp pretty printer. I'm using free Allegro CL and it looks like `text-edit-indentation` is the setting I was looking for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.